# Why is the "set /p"-method used in a batch script to read the first line of a text file not working in the body of a "for"-loop?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I tried to apply the answer given by [Spaceballs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/993642/spaceballs) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130116/windows-batch-commands-to-read-first-line-from-text-file) within the body of a [`for`-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591758/batch-script-loop).

*example.bat:*

```
@echo off

copy NUL %1
echo firstLine >> %1

echo /=======================/
for /l %%x in (1,1,3) do (
  echo %%x
  set /p A=< %1
  echo %A%
)
echo /=======================/

set /p A=< %1
echo %A%
```

Result of `start example.bat temp.txt`:

> ```
>      1 file(s) copied.
> ```
>
> /=======================/
>
> 1
>
> ECHO is OFF.
>
> 2
>
> ECHO is OFF.
>
> 3
>
> ECHO is OFF.
>
> /=======================/
>
> firstLine

Why is `set /p A=< %1` not working in the body of the `for`-loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that, apart from the loop variable, `cmd` expands variables in a batch file loop before the loop is executed, so, although `A` is being set within the loop, the value echoed is that prior to entry to the loop (ie blank). You can see that the value has been set by omitting the `set` before the final `echo`: the output will be the same.

The answer is to enable [*Delayed Expansion*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278456/enable-and-disable-delayed-expansion-what-does-it-do/22278518#22278518) and use `!A!` instead of `%A%`.

By the way the `copy` and `echo` commands at the beginning of the file are an unnecessarily long way of writing `echo firstLine > %1`.

So your batch file will work as expected if you modify it as follows:-

```
@echo off

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem copy NUL %1
rem echo firstLine >> %1
echo firstLine > %1

echo /=======================/
for /l %%x in (1,1,3) do (
  echo %%x
  set /p A=< %1
  echo !A!
)
echo /=======================/

rem set /p A=< %1
echo %A%
```

Note that you will be setting `A` to the same value in each pass of the loop. You will need to use a different technique if you want want each pass to show successive lines from the file.